# Count tags in an XML doc using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a pretty complicated XML document, that I want to parse. 
My first step is to count the number of < H > tags in my XML document. 
Here is a simplified version of my XML:

```
<file>
    xmlns="http://www.namespace.co.il"
    <H Id="1012532" W="2198.05">
        ///more tags
    </H>
    <H Id="623478" W="3215.05">
        ///more tags
    </H>
   etc.
</file>
```

Now what I want to do is to count the H elements, so here is what I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)

ns = {'nmsp': 'http://www.namespace.co.il'}
count =1
for HH in tree.iterfind(str(ns['nmsp']+':H')):
   print count
   count=count+1
```

When I run this code, nothing is printed to the console. 
Any idea why?

Comment: Your XML not correct ..missing > at the end of <file

Answer (score 2):

I think your question has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483851/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-count-tag-elements-in-a-xml-file-using-lxml-in-python).

The answer by zeekay is:

```
import lxml.etree
doc = lxml.etree.parse(xml)
count = doc.xpath('count(//author)')
```

(where, in your version, 'author' should be changed to 'H', I guess)

EDIT:

As to your own code (it took me some time to find it out):

Your loop should be

```
for HH in root.iterfind('nmsp:H', ns):
```

As is pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree), you need to give information about the namespace **dictionary** and not just the value under 'nmsp'.

Comment: Thank you! although I am still curious to know why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you looking for?

```
tree.iterfind('{http://www.namespace.co.il}H')
```